# Exception type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.ProtocolException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

My VS 2019 version is 16.8.5 and by default, the box for "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)" in "Tools > Options > Debugging > General" is unchecked as shown below.

[image: VS Debugging setting]

Usually, I haven't experienced "Exception type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.ProtocolException" for most of my projects but I realized it for the first time while debugging **EShopOnWeb** project and here it is.

[[image: exception error]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VILLw.png)

How could I get rid of this?
Let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks in advance.

Ganesh Acharya

Answer (score 0):

For me this occurs when I am using Microsoft's Edge as my browser. Unfortunately the only solution I have found is that I have to use Chrome as my browser.